# pydev import requests gives error unresolved import: requests

Tags: python, pydev

I am new to python in pydev (eclipse). 
I am trying to import requests and get an error:

```
import requests
```

error:

```
unresolved import: requests
```

In terminal I tried:

```
pip install requests
```

and it says

```
Requirement already satisfied
```

Also there is no error or warning when running brew doctor. What am I missing?

Comment: Is the terminal using the same python installation as pydev?

Comment: @PeterWood  Ah, no! thanks for pointing that out. Terminal is using brew installed python, pydev is using /usr/bin/python. deleted that and pointed to the brew python version and issue fixed. Thanks! If you can put your comment as answer I can mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: The thing is, you need to improve the question with more details, but the details actually give you the answer, so there's no real question. I'm voting to close as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that the Python pointed by pydev was different from the default python in the terminal that installed *requests* module.

The fix was to go to preferences -> pydev -> pydev interpreter -> click on the python (wrong python path) and remove, and then click on new to add the right python installed by brew. To find the python path installed by brew type `which python` in the terminal).

Answer (score 3):

First type python in the terminal -> Now you have the version of python.

Second Step: If you use Vscode in windows or mac, click on the gear button on the bottom left of the screen which is settings of Vscode,  select extensions in it, choose python from the list menu on left side, press command+shift+P or ctrl+shift+P and type "Select Interpreter", now select the version you have got in the first step. And you are good to go.